# I have a Visit visa paper for Dubai entry but with my old passport number in it

Tags: visas, filipino-citizens, uae, passport-renewals

[image]

I want to know if I still can enter Dubai with visit visa that is valid with my old passport?

But have my new passport along with it. My 'old' passport will expire May 17, 2017 and my new passport will be released February 1, 2017. The visit visa will expire on February 19, 2017.

Comment: There are a lot of [similar questions](http://travel.stackexchange.com/search?q=visa+old+new+passport) but for different countries.

Comment: Bring your new passport and the old one with the visa and you're still good to go...

Answer (score 1):

Good news, you are "Good to go" (though only if you are quick!). I've emboldened the relevant part from [TIMATIC](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=PH&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=AE&user=KLMB2C&subuser=KLMB2C) (courtesy KLM):

> / 27JAN17 / 0853 UTC
>
> National Philippines (PH)        Destination United Arab Emirates (AE)
>    United Arab Emirates (AE)
>
> Passport required.
>   - Passports and other documents accepted for entry must be valid for a minimum of 6 months from the arrival date.
>    - Passports and/or passport replacing documents issued to visitors NOT entering via Abu Dhabi (AUH) for a stay not exceeding 3 months,
>   must be valid for a minimum of 3 months from the arrival date. 
>   Admission and Transit Restrictions:
>
> - Admission refused to passengers with a hand-written passport at Dubai (DXB).
>
> Visa Issuance:
>   - E-visas can be obtained before departure at www.ednrd.ae .  Passengers must have a printed e-visa confirmation and airlines can check the validity of the e-visa on the same site by clicking on "Query GDRFA-D APP".  Visa required, except for Passengers with a normal passport and a confirmation that a visa has been approved before departure can obtain a visa on arrival for a maximum stay of 96 hours, 30 days or 90 days. Passengers must For details, click here 
>   Additional Information:
>
> - Passengers with dual nationality For details, click here.
> - All visitors must:
>
>   - hold documents for their next destination;
>   - have sponsor in the UAE to cover their stay.
> - **Valid visas in expired passports are accepted provided accompanied by new passport.**
>
>   Warning:
> - Visitors not holding return/onward tickets For details, click here could be refused entry.
> - Passengers accompanying a GCC Residents or a  GCC Citizen must travel with the sponsor in order to use the e-visa.
>
> Timaticweb Version 1.3 27 January 2017